# What happened to Krad Miner (the first javascript GPU miner)?

Tags: gpu-mining

[Krad Miner](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=9876.0) was the first javascript miner that supported GPUs. Now, [the website](http://kradminer.com/) yields a 502 error, and there has been no response to [post #57](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=9876.msg301179#msg301179) in the thread asking about it being dead.  Does anyone know what happened to it?

Comment: Maybe you should ask in the forum thread? I'm not entirely sure this is what stack exchange is for. This is more of a "have you seen person X" question.

Comment: @Evil post #57 in the thread already asks that question, and I've made an edit to reflect that (though the edit may take time to be accepted).  I don't see any problem having a discussion here about various interesting clients.

Comment: @nealmcb the problematic word there is "discussion." StackExchange is a question & answer site, not a forum. It's meant for questions, answers and comment on those questions and answers - not discussion. That said, others have asked questions as to the status and whereabouts of other Bitcoin projects and systems and we've answered them without argument so it seems that unless I've missed a big discussion on meta this question should be acceptable so long as it's actually answerable.

Comment: Alrighty, maybe so. I withdraw my complaint.

Comment: Good point, @David - I agree that discussion is not useful here - but I also think I slipped when I used it, since this question is suitable for being answered, not just discussed.

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to prefix my title with "What happened to". Isn't this a legitimate question now? If I were to ask "what happened to MyBitcoin, that wouldn't have been legit?" If there are answers in the forum already, feel free to link to them.

Comment: @ripper234 Actually it looks like when I was making another edit, I started to try to improve the lead-in to the question title, but forgot and just deleted those words - sorry.

Comment: Oh. No worries, as long as it's fixed now. @nealmcb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I purchased Krad Miner from the creator for the bounty cost of 50 BTC, and have released it as open source (Apache 2.0 license) on Github. Since the author has other projects using the Krad label, I have renamed it to [Tumen Miner](https://github.com/temujin9/tumen_miner). I would currently consider it alpha-quality; I have not run it, merely cleaned it up as best I could.

In the short term, I plan to fund some minor testing and development on it. Longer term, I may start coding on it myself, if I ever find the free time. I welcome donations in the form of bug reports, code pull requests, and BTC to pay the coders.

Merry Christmas, coiners.

Answer (score 5):

The creator took the service down after coming under DOS attacks. He offered to open source the software for a bounty, and eventually brought his offer price down to 50 Bitcoins. The message with the offer was on the kradminer website until a couple of weeks ago, and only recently has the site been inaccessible.